# error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix after adding ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, parsing, scrollview, prefix

After adding scrollview to my xml file i am getting error at 4th line.
I have tried moving `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` but still getting the same error.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.easy.convert.MainActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnbitsbytes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/btnbitsbytes" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnmassweight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnbitsbytes"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnbitsbytes"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:src="@drawable/btnmassweight" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ButtonConvert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnmassweight"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnmassweight"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:src="@drawable/btnlength" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ButtonConvert"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ButtonConvert"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:src="@drawable/btntemperature" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:src="@drawable/btndistance" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:src="@drawable/btnaboutus" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: delete the `xmlns` line from your `RelativeLayout` and try.

Comment: Duplicate `xmlns:android` is an error but it would produce another error message. If removing it doesn't help, consider posting more of your XML.

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem, but it's another observation: `"fill_parent"` is deprecated since API Level 8 (included). Use `"match_parent"`, instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` for `RelativeLayout`. That is need only for the root element ie  `ScrollView`

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>
```

Remove this

```
tools:context="com.easy.convert.MainActivity"
```

or add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 tools:context="com.easy.convert.MainActivity">
```

Edit:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
```

is the xml  name space for android.

```
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

`http://schemas.android.com/tools` is the namespace uri and the prefix is `tools`. You can find a list of tools attribute @

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes

Comment: @Tanmay post the entire xml

Comment: @Tanmay Remove this `tools:context="com.easy.convert.MainActivity"`

Comment: Instead of removing this line i have added xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" line. Can you tell me what is the use of tools:context ?

Comment: @Tanmay you could do that

Comment: Thanks a lot Raghunandan ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the `tools:context="com.easy.convert.MainActivity"` attribute. You need to declare the `tools` namespace prefix as well, like `android` is declared:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```